# Button in datatable is not working with switch case block (lightning component)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-button, datatable

Here is my code

```html
<aura:component  implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="LC_SearchController" >
    
    
    <aura:attribute name="recordList" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="allData" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="sortedBy" type="String" default="Name"/>
    <aura:attribute name="sortedDirection" type="string" default="asc" />
    <aura:attribute name="searchResult" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="searchKeyword" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Date1" type="date"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Date2" type="date"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Message" type="boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="TotalNumberOfRecord" type="integer" default="0" />
    
    <aura:attribute name="StudentObj" type="HocSinh__c" default="{'sobjectType':'HocSinh__c',
                                                                 'HoHocSinh__c':'',
                                                                 'TenHocSinh':'',
                                                                 'GioiTinh__c':'',
                                                                 'NgaySinh__c':'',
                                                                 'Diem1__c':'',
                                                                 'Diem2__c':'',
                                                                 'Diem3__c':'',
                                                                 'Lop__c':''
                                                                 }"/>
    <div aura:id="eventPopId"></div>
    <lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLibModal"/>
    
    <aura:attribute name="fieldMap" type ="Map"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
    <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_horizontal">
        
        <!--SearchField Group-->
        <lightning:layout class="layout" verticalAlign="end">
            <lightning:layoutItem size="4" padding="around-small" >
                <lightning:input value="{!v.searchKeyword}"
                                 placeholder="search students by name.."
                                 label="Tên:"
                                 />
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            
            <lightning:layoutItem size="4" padding="around-small" >
                <lightning:select aura:id="studentPicklist" value="{!v.StudentObj.Lop__c}" onchange="{!c.handleOnChange}" name="Lop__c" label="Lớp" required="false">
                    <option value="">--None--</option>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.fieldMap}" var="i" >
                        <option text="{!i.value}" value="{!i.key}"/>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </lightning:select>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            
         <div class="slds-grid">
            
            <lightning:layoutItem size="2" padding="around-small" >
                <lightning:input value="{!v.Date1}"
                                 type="date"
                                 placeholder="From..."
                                 label="Ngày sinh"
                                 />
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            
            <lightning:layoutItem size="2" padding="around-small" >
                <lightning:input value="{!v.Date2}"
                                 type="date"
                                 placeholder="...To"
                                 />
            </lightning:layoutItem>
          </div>    
            <!--Button Group-->
            <div class="slds-grid">
                <lightning:layoutItem size="3" padding="around-small">
                    <lightning:button onclick="{!c.Search}"
                                      variant="brand"
                                      label="Search"
                                      iconName="utility:search"
                                      class = "searchbtn"/> 
                </lightning:layoutItem>
                
                <lightning:layoutItem size="3" padding="around-small">
                    <lightning:button onclick="{!c.InsertPopup}"
                                      variant="brand"
                                      label="Thêm mới"
                                      class = "insertbtn"/> 
                </lightning:layoutItem>
            </div>      
        </lightning:layout>  
        
        <lightning:layout multipleRows="true" horizontalAlign="center">
            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="12">
                <lightning:datatable keyField="Id" data="{!v.recordList}"
                                     columns="{!v.columns}"
                                     hideCheckboxColumn="false"
                                     onsort="{!c.updateSorting}"
                                     sortedBy="{!v.sortedBy}"
                                     sortedDirection="{!v.sortedDirection}"
                                     onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction }"/>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
    </div>        
</aura:component>
```

----------Controller----------

```javascript
({
    init: function (component, event, helper) {
        helper.getStudents(component,event,helper);
        helper.getPickListValue(component,helper);
    },
    
    Search: function(component,event,helper){
        helper.SearchHelper(component, event);
    },
    
    
    
    updateSorting: function (component, event, helper) {
        var fieldName = event.getParam('fieldName');
        var sortDirection = event.getParam('sortDirection');
        component.set("v.sortedBy", fieldName);
        component.set("v.sortedDirection", sortDirection);
        helper.sortData(component, fieldName, sortDirection);
    },
    
    InsertPopup : function (component, event, helper) {
        var modalBody;
        var modalFooter;
        $A.createComponents([
            ["c:LC_Insert",{}],
            ["c:LC_Insert_Footer",{}]
        ],
                            function(content, status){
                                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                                    modalBody = content[0];
                                    modalFooter = content[1];
                                    component.find('overlayLibModal').showCustomModal({
                                        header: "Modal",
                                        body: modalBody,
                                        footer: modalFooter,
                                        showCloseButton: true,
                                        
                                        closeCallback: function() {
                                            console.log('You closed the alert!');
                                        }
                                    })
                                }
                            }
                           );
    },
    
    handleRowAction: function(component,event,helper){
        var action = event.getParam('action');
        var row = event.getParam('row');
        
        
        switch (action.name) {
            case 'editRecord':
                alert('Cập nhật được bấm!');
                helper.editStudent(component, event);
                break;
            case 'deleteRecord':
                alert('Xóa đối tượng được bấm!');
                helper.deleteStudent(component, event);
                break;
        }
        
        
    },
    
    
    
})
```

------------Helper-----------

```javascript
({
    getStudents : function(component, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getStudentList");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            var data;
            if(state === 'SUCCESS'){
                component.set('v.columns', [
            { label: 'Họ', fieldName: 'HoHocSinh__c', type: 'text' },
            { label: 'Tên', fieldName: 'StudentUrl', type: 'url', typeAttributes: { label:{fieldName:"TenHocSinh__c"}, target:'_self'} },
            { label: 'Ngày sinh', fieldName: 'NgaySinh__c', type: 'date' },
            { label: 'Giới tính', fieldName: 'GioiTinh__c', type: 'checkbox' },
            { label: 'Điểm 1', fieldName: 'Diem1__c', type: 'number' },
            { label: 'Điểm 2', fieldName: 'Diem2__c', type: 'number' },
            { label: 'Điểm 3', fieldName: 'Diem3__c', type: 'number' },
            { label: 'Điểm TB', fieldName: 'DiemTB__c', type: 'number' },
            { label: 'Tình trạng', fieldName: 'TinhTrang__c', type: 'text' },
            { label: '',  type: 'button', initialWidth: 150 , typeAttributes: {label:'Cập nhật', disable:'false', name:'editRecord', value:"edit", name:"edit" } },
            { label: '',  type: 'button', initialWidth: 150 , typeAttributes: {label:'Xóa', disable:'false',name:'deleteRecord', value:"delete", name:"delete" } }
        ]);
                
                var results = response.getReturnValue();
                results.forEach(function(record){
                record['StudentUrl'] ='/lightning/r/HocSinh__c/'+record['Id']+'/view';
                });
                component.set("v.recordList", results);
                component.set("v.allData", results);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    
    SearchHelper: function(component, event) {
        var action = component.get('c.searchHocSinh');
        action.setParams
        (
            {ten: component.get("v.searchKeyword"),
             lop: component.get("v.StudentObj.Lop__c"),
             ngay1: component.get("v.Date1"),
             ngay2: component.get("v.Date2")}
        );
        //alert("Ten: " + component.get("v.searchKeyword") + " Lop: " + component.get("v.StudentObj.Lop__c") + " Ngay1: " + component.get("v.Date1")+ " Ngay2: " + component.get("v.Date2"));
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) { 
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var storeResponse = response.getReturnValue();
                
                // set numberOfRecord attribute value with length of return value from server
                component.set("v.TotalNumberOfRecord", storeResponse.length);
                
                // set searchResult list with return value from server.
                component.set("v.recordList", storeResponse); 
                
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    
   
    
    getPickListValue: function(component,event){
        var action = component.get("c.getClassFieldValue");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var result = response.getReturnValue();
                var fieldMap = [];
                for(var key in result){
                    fieldMap.push({key: key, value: result[key]});
                }
                component.set("v.fieldMap", fieldMap);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    
    
    
    editStudent: function(component,event){
        
    },
    
    deleteStudent: function(component,event){
        var hocsinh = event.getParam('row');        
        var action = component.get("c.deleteStudent");
        action.setParams({
            "hocsinh": hocsinh
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) 
                           {          
            if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS" ) 
            {
                var rows = component.get('v.StudentObject');
                var rowIndex = rows.indexOf(hocsinh);
                rows.splice(rowIndex, 1);
                component.set('v.StudentObject', rows);
                this.showToast("Success!","success","The record has been delete successfully.");
            }
            else
            {
                this.showToast("ERROR","error",JSON.stringify(response.getError())); 
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: i clicked on the button and it doesnt show the alert, but i solved it 5 minutes ago, i put 2 'name' attributes in the typeAttribute, so the switch case block doesnt get the exact name

Comment: just need to delete 1 name attribute and it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

In your `columns` definition you have the `name` attribute present twice.

While I'm not exactly sure how `aura` handles this, I'm reasonably sure that you code will need to change from this:

```
{ label: '',  type: 'button', initialWidth: 150 , typeAttributes: 
  {label:'Cập nhật', disable:'false', name:'editRecord', value:"edit", name:"edit" } },
{ label: '',  type: 'button', initialWidth: 150 , typeAttributes: 
  {label:'Xóa', disable:'false',name:'deleteRecord', value:"delete", name:"delete" } }
```

To this:

```
{ label: '',  type: 'button', initialWidth: 150 , typeAttributes: 
  {label:'Cập nhật', disable:'false', name:'editRecord', value:"edit"} },
{ label: '',  type: 'button', initialWidth: 150 , typeAttributes: 
  {label:'Xóa', disable:'false',name:'deleteRecord', value:"delete"} }
```

See the duplicate `name` attribute?

```
name:'deleteRecord', value:"delete", name:"delete"
```

Note I've edited the JSON so that it doesn't show scrollbars for readability.

Also, until your code is formatted properly, there potentially many other errors that I was not able to detect because the code was so hard to read.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i just fixed it and i works great